# I can't find a way to implement messages in my school database on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm working on a school database on which I would like to implement messages that will be created by the schools for the parents to view.

**The workflow goes like this:**

**1.** The school sends a message to a certain group of students, it could be a message to all the students from that school, or a message to just the first year, or a message to classroom 1B (1 being the year and B the group), or even a message to just 1 student.

**2.** Parents access a platform on which they will see the messages regarding their children.

For example:

- if the school sends a message to the classroom 1B, only parents with children on that classroom will be able to see it.
- if the school sends a message to the first year, only parents with
  children on the first year will see it.

**What I need help with is:**

- How could I arrange the database in order to accomplish the message
  filtering (**By school**, **by year**, **by classroom** (1B, 2A,
  etc.) and **by student**)?
- What would be the sentence that I need to use in order to retrieve
  the messages for a parent regarding their children?

I hope I explained myself well, please feel free to ask any question you have, and thank you so much :)

Here's a pic of the database:

[image: My DB]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Note that `group` is a reserved word.

Comment: How are messages stored which address e.g. a group or year, not a single student? Or is every message duplicated for every single recipient?

Comment: You may want to consider creating another entity which represents the n:m relation between messages and students.

Comment: Hey Jimmy, I created that "message" table hoping to be able to use it to store the content of the message, the school that's creating it (on the "ID_school" field), and the students regarding the message, for example, if I wanted to send a message to just a single student I would put the student ID in the "ID_student" field, and the other fields would remain Null. The problem came when I tried to create the sentence for the parents to view the messages and ignore the fields with Null.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, for this question "What would be the sentence that I need to use in order to retrieve the messages for a parent regarding their children?" you could use a simple inner join between message and parent_detail on id_students are equals where id_parent is your parentID:

```
SELECT * FROM `message` m
INNER JOIN `parent_detail` p_d on p_d.ID_student = m.ID_student
WHERE p_d.ID_detail = 'parent_id_variable'
```

Regarding the first question, using the same principle, you need to use an inner join between message students and schools (if you want the name of the school and not only the ID) and apply in where condition what parameter you want. 
For example, by school => message.ID_school, by school and by year => message.ID_school and students.year.

Comment: What about messages not addressed directly to a single student but to a group or year of students?

Comment: Yeah that's the problem, the part where the messages are addressed to a group or year

Comment: Using groupID or in your case classID should resolve that issue. Another way would be modifying/designing the existing ID to hold the details of their year and class info.